# Sending multiple raw packet over Bluetooth with Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt, sockets, bluetooth

I wrote this snippet of Python code (using pybluez) to send raw BNEP Bluetooth packet over L2CAP. The purpose is to do some fuzzing-like testing.

```
 BNEP_PSM = 0x000F
 btSock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP)
 btSock.connect(('<some BDADDR>', BNEP_PSM))

 for i in range(10):
    btSock.send('<some payload>')
```

This is working quite fine and as expected creating multiple BNEP packet even if the payload is malformed.

Now, I'm trying to write the same function in C++ using Qt, but it is not working the same way. An excerpt of the code is the following:

```
QBluetoothSocket btSock(QBluetoothServiceInfo::L2capProtocol);
btSock.connectToService(QBluetoothAddress("<some BDADDR>"), QBluetoothUuid::Bnep);

QObject::connect(&btSock, &QBluetoothSocket::connected, [&btSock](){
    int i = 10;
    while (i--)
        btSock.write("<some payload>");
});
```

Running it with `i = 1` works just fine sending a single packet with the specified payload.
Running it with `i = 10` will results in a **single packet** with the payload equals to *ten times the specified payload*.

For instance setting a payload of "AAAA" in a loop of 3 will result in the first case using Python in

```
+------------+----+       +------------+----+       +------------+----+
|L2CAP Header|AAAA|  -->  |L2CAP Header|AAAA|  -->  |L2CAP Header|AAAA|
+------------+----+       +------------+----+       +------------+----+
```

In the second case using Qt in

```
+------------+------------+
|L2CAP Header|AAAAAAAAAAAA|
+------------+------------+
```

How could I force Qt socket's `write` to behave like Python socket's `send`?

### UPDATE:

Looking at the documentation it says that

> The bytes are written when control goes back to the event loop

How could I force buffer to flush before going back to the event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found a proper solution using `QBluetoothSocket`'s methods, but I made it work with a little hack.

Just used C header `sys/socket.h` (I need to support POSIX compliant only OSs) and changed

```
btSock.write("<some payload>");
```

to

```
send(btSock.socketDescriptor(), "<some payload>", <payload length>);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How could I force buffer to flush before going back to the event loop?

You can't, because the sending can only be done asynchronously, not synchronously.

But we can queue a flush the same way the packets are queued. Namely: send each packet after the previous one has been sent. Thus we shall send it every time the event loop has processed all other work. The idiom for that is zero-duration timers - note that this has nothing at all to do with timers, it's a weird overloading of the timer concept that really makes no sense otherwise.

```
int i = 10;
while (i--)
  QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this]{ m_btSocket.write("<some payload>"); });
```

`m_btSocket` must be a member of the class, and must be a value member - otherwise the code will be unsafe.

If you wish to ensure that stale packets are dumped in case of a disconnection and won't affect any subsequent connections, keep track of their generation and send only if it's current:

```
class Foo : public QObject {
  unsigned int m_generation = {}; // unsigned: modulo math w/o overflows
  QBluetoothSocket m_btSocket{QBluetoothServiceInfo::L2CAP};
  ...
  bool isBtConnected() const { return m_btSocket::state() == QBluetoothSocket::ConnectedState; }
  void sendSinglePacket(const QByteArray & data) {
    if (!isBtConnected()) return;
    auto gen = m_generation;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this, gen, data] {
      if (m_generation == gen)
        m_btSocket.write(data);
    });
  }
  Foo(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(&m_btSocket, &QBluetoothSocket::Disconnected, this, [this]{
      m_generation++; // drops all in-flight packets
    });
    ...
  }
};
```